# Debezium connector fails after "Searching for WAL resume position"

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, ksqldb

I'm using debezium postgres connector to capture few tables' record in kafka. The debezium connector closed after "Searching for WAL resume position". I've give the error below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
2022-12-12 07:46:51,834 INFO   Postgres|postgres|streaming  Searching for WAL resume position   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource]
2022-12-12 07:46:56,548 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=ksqldb-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:223)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:149)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:474)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:387)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.execute(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:354)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:72)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.apicurio.registry.rest.client.exception.RestClientException
        at io.apicurio.registry.rest.client.impl.ErrorHandler.parseError(ErrorHandler.java:95)
        at io.apicurio.rest.client.JdkHttpClient.sendRequest(JdkHttpClient.java:205)
        at io.apicurio.registry.rest.client.impl.RegistryClientImpl.createArtifact(RegistryClientImpl.java:240)
        at io.apicurio.registry.rest.client.RegistryClient.createArtifact(RegistryClient.java:143)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.DefaultSchemaResolver.lambda$handleAutoCreateArtifact$2(DefaultSchemaResolver.java:236)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.ERCache.lambda$getValue$0(ERCache.java:142)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.ERCache.retry(ERCache.java:181)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.ERCache.getValue(ERCache.java:141)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.ERCache.getByContent(ERCache.java:121)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.DefaultSchemaResolver.handleAutoCreateArtifact(DefaultSchemaResolver.java:234)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.DefaultSchemaResolver.getSchemaFromRegistry(DefaultSchemaResolver.java:115)
        at io.apicurio.registry.resolver.DefaultSchemaResolver.resolveSchema(DefaultSchemaResolver.java:88)
        at io.apicurio.registry.utils.converter.ExtJsonConverter.fromConnectData(ExtJsonConverter.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$5(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:474)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:173)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:207)
        ... 12 more
2022-12-12 07:46:56,548 INFO   ||  Stopping down connector   [io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask]
2022-12-12 07:46:56,585 INFO   Postgres|postgres|streaming  WAL resume position 'null' discovered   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource]
2022-12-12 07:46:56,588 INFO   Postgres|postgres|streaming  Connection gracefully closed   [io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection]
2022-12-12 07:46:56,691 INFO   Postgres|postgres|streaming  Connection gracefully closed   [io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was Apicurio error. The error was all the containers were running in one network in which Apicurio was not added. I added Apicurio in that network , then the issue got resolved.